# Why is tee stopping in the middle when piped with nohup?

Tags: pipe, nohup, tee

I'm running a script (in a Laravel project) that takes a few hours to complete. `nohup` to prevent it from exiting if my ssh session is disconnected.

```shell
nohup php artisan do:thing 2>&1 | tee ~/tmp
```

It starts off nicely, but after some time, I get a broken pipe error and it stops outputing things, and `tee` stops as well - the doc stops at that point.

I guess it's because the `tee` process got killed by the ssh session drop? Can I prevent it?

Could I maybe disown the tee process and prevent ssh from terminating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nohup` applies to the first command. When you close your shell the `tee` no longer can write to its normal output (*stdout*) and exits. This causes the first command to exit because it now too can no longer write to its pipe output.

Try this

```
nohup php artisan do:thing >~/tmp 2>&1
```

Or if you have `screen`,

```
screen sh -c 'php artisan do:thing 2>&1 | tee ~/tmp'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it! I didn't know I could specify two different outputs that way. Interesting

Comment: @JeremyBelolo that's what `tee` does. See the description in the first paragraph of the documentation/manual, `man tee`

Comment: Got myself a rtfm. Probably well deserved :D Thanks!

Comment: I don't use that expression myself. The documentation is decidedly reference material not tutorials. You have to know what you're looking for